# Novel CSS dropdown/Megamenu

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Hi I want to create a new type of nav dropdown (new as in I haven't seen it before).

Basically when I hover over a nav item, a dropdown box should appear below the nav. The difference to a normal dropdown is that I want this dropdown to contain all of the navs sub items(not just the items belonging to the hovered item). So in my code example, if one was to hover over Nav 1 then all items a-i would appear.

```
<ul>
            <li><a href="#">Nav 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">item a</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item b</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item c</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">item d</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item e</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item f</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">item g</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item h</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item i</a></li>
                </ul>                   
            </li>
        </ul>
```

**Note**: The dropdown should be the same width as the nav and each nav item's links should appear below it. [I've attached a sketch!](http://i52.tinypic.com/2djomf.jpg)

I had thought about putting a div containing the dropdown within the UL and have it appear on ul.hover but then that won't validate and you wouldn't be able to target which li was being hovered.

It might not be possible to achieve this using just css, if someone could let me know that would be great.

Sorry if this seems like rambling... hopefully someone will understand what I'm after!

Comment: Possibly you haven't seen this before as it is a bit of a cumbersome UI...  What is the requirement to have this like this?

Comment: Why would you want to do something like this?

Comment: I understand what you want. You're right that "it might not be possible to achieve this using just css" - it will require javascript (unless you want to duplicate *all* the drop downs for each button..). I agree with @Paddy, this is confusing - why bother having separate buttons if each one just does the same thing? I hope you want to do something slightly different with the current drop down. (different background colour or transparency?)

Comment: It's more of an exploration of how navs could be done. I think it could be a really nice nav and work well.

@thirtydot the plan would be to have the hovered column styled to stand out more, while still being able to see other sub-item links.

Feedback appreciated all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So hovering over any part of the navigation shows all the sub-levels?

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MwB9e/1/) of the basic functionality; you then need to style it using CSS.

eg

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/hybrid/

http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

(there's hundreds of examples on Google)

Comment: Your css solution is just what I want, it's beautiful and can't believe I didn't think of that... I added another line of css to highlight the hovered list's sub items.

http://jsfiddle.net/MwB9e/5/

Comment: @Usheen: I recommend you change `margin-left: 10px` to use `padding` instead. That way, you can move onto lists other than the one below the link you hovered over. [With margin = the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/MwB9e/7/). [With padding = better](http://jsfiddle.net/MwB9e/6/). Also, I doubt you care, but that won't work in IE6 without some further additions.

Comment: Good call on the padding. ie6 can only hover on an anchor is the problem I'm assuming. I usually include ie7.js on all my pages so that solves that. http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/